# PHP MySql $_GET problems

Tags: php, html

I have tried to search through the forums but I am a novice and am getting more confused.

I am trying to bring an input from a form and use it as a variable in a MySql query.  A shortened version of the form is -

```
echo "<form  method=\"get\" action=\"\">";
echo "<tr><td>Leave:</td><td><input value=\"".$_SESSION['leave']."\" class=\"text\" autocomplete=\"off\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" /></td></tr>";
echo "</form>";
```

I am then trying to store the input into a variable using code -

```
$newVar = $_GET['leave'];
```

However I am getting an undefined index error.

Can anyone help with this? Sorry if its a very basic problem :)

Comment: try echo '<form  method="get" action="">';

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with your `HTML`. You need to name the `input`.

```
echo '<input name="leave" class="text" autocomplete="off" type="text" value="' . $_SESSION['leave'] . '" />';
```

Answer (score 1):

You declaring the "value attribute twice, you need to declare name:

```
echo "<form  method=\"get\" action=\"\">";
echo "<tr><td>Leave:</td><td><input name=\"".$_SESSION['leave']."\" class=\"text\" autocomplete=\"off\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" /></td></tr>";
echo "</form>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<form  method="get" action="">';
echo "<tr><td>Leave:</td><td><input value='{$_SESSION['leave']}' class='text' autocomplete='off' type='text' name='leave'/></td></tr>";
echo "</form>";
```

If you use single quotes and doubles quotes alternating, you can make your code look nicer.

For your problem, you're missing your input name:

```
<input type=".." name="leave" ..>
```

Also, notice in your output of the field, you have the value set to the session value and an empty value near the end.

```
value=\"\"
```